# proper vertical alignment for angled x-axis ticks in faceted ggplot figures

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

i'm looking for some help in creating a faceted plot with angeled x-axis tick labels, which is probably best explained by the following example:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(group=factor(c('sex','sex','race','race')), variable=c('Female','Male','White','African American'), value=1:4)
p <- ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=value), data=df) 
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ group, scale="free")
p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1))
ggsave(p, file='faceted.pdf', width=6, height=4)
```

which produces this figure where the x-ticks on the right are misaligned:

[image: misaligned x-axis ticks]

it seems that the problem is introduced when using `scale="free"` in the `facet_grid` and is related to the varying tick label length.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/221 that has apparently been fixed in ggplot2 0.9 and later.

```
> help(package='ggplot2')
                Information on package ‘ggplot2’    
Description:
Package:            ggplot2
Type:               Package
Title:              An implementation of the Grammar of Graphics
Version:            0.8.9
```

(Too bad for me!)

Bug reproducible with:

```
qplot(reorder(model, hwy), hwy, data=mpg) +
    facet_grid(. ~ manufacturer, scales="free") +
    opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really got just a few x-labels - who needs ticks mate? Suppress them with `axis.ticks` and get rid of horizontal/vertical justification.

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(group=factor(c('sex','sex','race','race')),
                 variable=c('Female','Male','White','African American'), 
                 value=1:4)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ group, scale="free") 
p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=45), 
              axis.ticks = theme_blank(),axis.title.y=theme_blank())
ggsave(p, file='no_ticks.png', width=6, height=4)
```

[image]

Comment: the ticks are useful to guide the eye when there are more factors, but this is a nice workaround. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late (i.e. 9 years after the last answer ;) but still interesting, here is another way to define the angle of axes labels (here: 90° rotation of x-axis labels):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

(where `vjust` and `hjust` are *vertical* and *horizontal alignment* respectively)